# Can I set env vars for dependencies in setup-tools?

Tags: python, setuptools

Is it possible to set env vars to be used by dependencies set in the `setup.py` file of a package?

Specifically; the `lxml` package is a dependency of one of my packages. To help ease deployment I want to set `STATIC_DEPS=true` and some CFLAGS for `lxml` in the setup.py file for my package, so that our users can just `easy_install my-package` without any install issues.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that the default behaviour?
Just

```
export STATIC_DEPS=true; easy_install lxml
```